# How can I set or select an option in a SELECT element on Javascript

Tags: javascript, html-select

I have a webpage that's not mine, but I want to get values of a SELECT element.

For example:

```
    <select name="ctl00$MainContent$CldFecha$DdlAnio" id="DdlAnio" class="calendarCombo2" onchange="ValidateYear();" style="width: 60px; display: none;" sb="83980340">
    <option value="2011">2011</option>
    <option value="2012">2012</option>
    <option value="2013">2013</option>
    <option value="2014">2014</option>
    <option selected="selected" value="2015">2015</option>
```

When I click a Button I want to set any of this options, for example 2013.

I know how to get the selected value, doing this:

```
document.getElementById('DdlAnio').value
```

And for get the selected index:

```
document.getElementById('DdlAnio').selectedIndex
```

However I thought based on W3Schools, these may work to set the option wanted:

```
document.getElementById('DdlAnio').value = "2013"
document.getElementById('DdlAnio').selectedIndex = "2"
```

But nothing happens, what Am I doing wrong?

Also I tried with:

```
document.getElementById('DdlAnio').options[DdlAnio.selectedIndex].value = 2013
```

And nothing happens

Comment: maybe change your style `style="... display: none;"` because it does not show up.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to address via the form name and the name of the element. Or via `getElementById()`.

```js
function setOption1() {
    document.form1['ctl00$MainContent$CldFecha$DdlAnio'].selectedIndex = 2;
}

function setOption2() {
    document.getElementById('DdlAnio').selectedIndex = 2;
}
```

```html
<form name="form1">
    <select name="ctl00$MainContent$CldFecha$DdlAnio" id="DdlAnio">
        <option value="2011">2011</option>
        <option value="2012">2012</option>
        <option value="2013">2013</option>
        <option value="2014">2014</option>
        <option selected="selected" value="2015">2015</option>
    </select>
    <button onclick="setOption1()">setOption1</button>
    <button onclick="setOption2()">setOption2</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

This `document.getElementById('DdlAnio').value = '2013';` should work.

Try to temporarily remove the `onchange="ValidateYear();"` (not knowing what it actualy does though).

Answer (score 0):

Create a button on your page

```
<input type="button" onclick="setSelectTo('2012');" value="set year"/>
```

Create onclick handler for the button to take the value, which can iterate through the options of the select box and set the selected index.

```
function setSelectTo(yr) {
    var selList = document.getElementById('DdlAnio');
    for ( var i=0; i<selList.options.length; i++ ) {
       if ( selList.options[i].value == yr ) {
                selList.selectedIndex = i;
                break;
       } 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you are right!. I made a simulacra, copying this part of code and I saw that with this: `display:none`. Control doesnt appear. But when I deleted I can ser any value desired con the `SELECT`.

Now , how can I modify this CSS attribute? Im planning to set attribute like this:

```
Document.GetElementbyID('DdlAnio').setAttribute ('style','style=width:60px)
```

In order to only preserve that attribute. So after doing this, I will be able to ser any value of the `SELECT`. right??

Comment: Other people un other forum suggests to modify ARGUMENTS. is it right??

Comment: In fact I tested It, The webpage that I'm testing has the Select Controls hidden by CSS Styles and Has drawed controls.    When I reassign Attributes, control gets visible:   document.getElementById('DdlAnio').setAttribute('style','width: 80px')       So but after this when I try to selectindex in the next line, it doesn't work and again doesn't appear